# Type conversion in DM script

Tags: dm-script

all:
I'd like to read a config file in DM script, then use the information in the config file as flags. For example, in the function TagGroup DLGCreateChoice( TagGroup &items, number value ), the value is used to pre-define the choice. But when I read something from a config file, it's string. Though I can use some if clause to convert the string to number, it's not straightfoward enough. Is there any method to convert the type?

For example, currently I will use the code as below

```
//some code to get the string value, the variable is flag_string
if (flag_string == "1") flag_value = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the command `val()` as in:

```c
string str = "1234.53345345"
number num = val(str)
Result("\n '"+str+"' evaluates to:"+num+ " ( Formatted:"+Format(num,"%20.5f")+" )" )
```